# Batch script not outputting files with this code

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop

This script should output each word in a 10-word sentence stored in line 1 (When called with SeparateLine.bat (filename) 1, but it shows no errors nor outputs or makes the file.

I have already tried removing the parenthesis in the `(echo %%a > 1.txt)` and the ones below, with no avail. I've also tried different formats for where the outputs go, still no avail.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~1" echo file not found & exit /b 1
if "%~2"=="" echo line not defined & exit /b
if "%~2"=="1" set line=1 & goto start
set /a line=%~2-1
:start
For /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10* usebackq skip=%line% delims= " %%A in ("%~1") do (                       
    if not "%%A"=="" (echo %%A > 1.txt)
    if not "%%B"=="" (echo %%B > 2.txt)
    if not "%%C"=="" (echo %%C > 3.txt)
    if not "%%D"=="" (echo %%D > 4.txt)
    if not "%%E"=="" (echo %%E > 5.txt)
    if not "%%F"=="" (echo %%F > 6.txt)
    if not "%%G"=="" (echo %%G > 7.txt)
    if not "%%H"=="" (echo %%H > 8.txt)
    if not "%%I"=="" (echo %%I > 9.txt)
    if not "%%J"=="" (echo %%J > 10.txt)
    GOTO endforloop
)
:endforloop
```

With the file that contains one, two, three... ten separated by spaces, it should output 10 files (maximum word limit is 10) each containing word 1-10 of the line (I specified line 1 in the second parameter as the words are on the first line), but the actual results are... nothing. Literally, it acts as if it completed successfully but no files are made and, well, no error codes.

Comment: You can't have `:lable` or `goto` inside brackets. Plus it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: As I said, I have already tried removing the brackets.

Comment: Remove the `goto` it is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @catcat  Are you sure? How do you know it's unnecessary?

Comment: Provide some sample input text, and your expected output, so we can help you try it.

Comment: @catcat the goto label is not totally unnecessary, the OP's intend it to only print the content of the given line then exit the loop, if you remove the goto, it will repeat the loop for the remaining lines...

Comment: There's a logical error: if you want to extract line N of a file, you need to skip N-1 lines; note that `skip=0` is not accepted by `for /F`, but you could avoid that by: `if line leq 0 (set "SKIP=") else (set "SKIP=skip=%LINE%")`, then change the loop to `for /F "tokens=1-10 usebackq %SKIP% delims= " %%A in ("%~1") do ( ... )`...

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be what you are looking for. Note you cannot use the pre-defined variable in `skip=%line%` you need to instead use `more +%line%`, there is not a need to define each token `token=1,2,3,4...` etc. simply use `tokens1-10` and and last, but not least no need to use `delims=` as whitespace is the default delimeter:

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~1" echo file not found & exit /b 1
if "%~2"=="" echo line not defined & exit /b
if "%~2"=="1" set line=1 & goto start
set /a line=%~2-1
:start
For /f "tokens=1-10" %%A in ('type "%~1" ^| more +%line%') do (              
    if "%%A" NEQ "" echo %%A
    if not "%%B"=="" echo %%B
    if not "%%C"=="" echo %%C
    if not "%%D"=="" echo %%D
    if not "%%E"=="" echo %%E
    if not "%%F"=="" echo %%F
    if not "%%G"=="" echo %%G
    if not "%%H"=="" echo %%H
    if not "%%I"=="" echo %%I
    if not "%%J"=="" echo %%J
    goto :EOF
)
```

There is a flaw however with your `line` variable.

if a user selects `0` it will do `0 -` = -1`and then set the lines to skip`-1`if a user selects`2`it will set it to skip`1` which is not what a user requested, so I suggest you clarify what your intensions are with the skip lines, but perhaps just get rid of it completely, like:

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~1" echo file not found & exit /b 1
if "%~2"=="" echo line not defined & exit /b
set /a line=%~2
:start
For /f "tokens=1-10" %%A in ('type "%~1" ^| more +%line%') do (              
    if "%%A" NEQ "" echo %%A
    if not "%%B"=="" echo %%B
    if not "%%C"=="" echo %%C
    if not "%%D"=="" echo %%D
    if not "%%E"=="" echo %%E
    if not "%%F"=="" echo %%F
    if not "%%G"=="" echo %%G
    if not "%%H"=="" echo %%H
    if not "%%I"=="" echo %%I
    if not "%%J"=="" echo %%J
    goto :EOF
)
```